# Show progressDialog in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show a progressDialog on my page when the user clicks on the button.On click of button i am sorting my results that is a List.Now how can we show a progressDialog on click of a button.Please suggest me

This function i am using to sort that data :

```
public void sortByDate(View v) {
        Collections.sort(tripParseData.getDetails());
        setData(tripParseData);
    }
```

After **@Monica** Suggestion

```
public void sortByDate(View v) {
        new LoadData().execute();

    }

class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Collections.sort(tripParseData.getCoroprateBookingDetails());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            setApprovalDetailsData(tripParseData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to show a progressdialog until the sorting process is done here

Comment: you should look AsynkTask : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: There are sooo many ways to indicate an ongoing progress. Please read the documentation first, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) and especially [here](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html). Google explicitely discourages the use of `ProgressDialog` so please stick to those guidelines

Comment: Use asncTask... In onPreexecute open dialog, in doBackground do sorting process & in onPostexecute dismiss dialog

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     Paste This Class in ur activity and call new LoadData().execute to start the prgress dialog :
> ```

```
    class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

          super.onPreExecute();  
          ProgressDialog pg=new ProgressDialog(ChartsActivity.this);
          pg=pg.show(ChartsActivity.this, "Loding", "Plz Wait...");
            }



 @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
sortByDate();
    }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {      
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pg.dismiss();
    }
    }
```

Comment: where i have to put this can u suggest me

Comment: for sorting why i use asynk task it's not good to use it for sorting

Comment: i am getting exception

Comment: what is exectopin? soory i hv edited the answer paste this class

Comment: and when u want to start : new LoadData().execute();

Comment: MainActivity has leaked window

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38868/discussion-between-rahul-and-monica)

Comment: can we chat somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

you have to call progressdiolog.show before the long calculation starts and then the calculation has to run in a separate thread. A soon as this thread is finished, you have to call pd.dismiss() to close the prgoress dialog.

here you can see an example:

the progressdialog is created and displayed and a thread is called to run a heavy calculation:

```
Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       pd = ProgressDialog.show(lexs, "Search", "Searching...", true, false);
       Search search = new Search(   ...   );
       SearchThread searchThread = new SearchThread(search);
       searchThread.start();
    }
```

and here the thread:

```
private class SearchThread extends Thread {

        private Search search;

        public SearchThread(Search search) {
            this.search = search;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {         
            search.search();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }

        private Handler handler = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                displaySearchResults(search);
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        };
    }
```

Don't forget to vote me up :)

Comment: will u please suggest me how could i do this is code for the function that i have mentioned above will be thankfull to u

Comment: put your code in void OnClick(View v) when the button will call, your progress will start automatically

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it but I think it can help you.

Declare these two objects in your class and member variables.

```
Thread thread = null;
ProgressDialog bar = null;
```

Use this logic on your button click listener it can work in your case. I have not tested it but It will give you Idea how things should work. you can also use handlemessage in place of runonuithread

```
    if (thread == null
     || (thread != null && !thread.isAlive())) { 
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //DISPLAY YOUR PROGRESS BAR HERE.
                        bar = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "LOADING..", "PLEASE WAIT..");
                    }
                });
                // SORT COLLECTION HERE
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //CLOSE YOUR PROGRESS BAR HERE.
                        bar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: There are different ways to perform. You can use asyncTask also. You can simply use a thread also or you can use a timer also.

Answer (score 0):

try to use AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Sample code:

```
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             //Show UI
             //Start your progress bar

             showProgress();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
             // do your sorting process 
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                          //Show UI
             //dismiss your progress bar
            hideProgress();
        }

    };
task.execute((Void[])null);
```

Show and hide progress code

```
public void showProgress() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
                "Loading. Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    public void hideProgress() {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```